Supabase function for querying related tables with GraphQL
Pretty bummed to find out Supabase does not allow queries on related tables out of the box with GraphQL. I'm trying to create a function to help accomplish this but I'm stuck. When I run this SQL script it does so successfully but when I try to hit it in the GraphiQL playground the function doesn't exist.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION filter_events_search(gender VARCHAR)
  RETURNS TABLE(
    id UUID
  )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT
    e.id
  FROM 
    events e 
    JOIN teams t ON e.team_id = t.id
  WHERE
    t.gender = filter_events_search.gender;
END;
$$;

Any suggestions? I've tried stable vs immutable as well.

naming variables like column names is very very bad and must be avoided

Got it figured out in case anyone else gets stuck.
create or replace function filter_events_search(gender varchar, birth_year int, state varchar)
  returns setof events
  stable
  language sql
  as
$$
  select
   e.*
  from
    events e
  join teams t on e.team_id = t.id
  where
    e.status = 'pending'
  and
    t.gender = filter_events_search.gender
  and
    t.birth_year = filter_events_search.birth_year
  and
    t.state = filter_events_search.state
  order by
    e.date;
$$;


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
